# Song recording on Yamaha instruments

Tags: recording, sequencer

I have a Yamaha CVP-805 which I enjoy very much. I am trying to understand the logic behind its MIDI record module. Why is there a "right-hand" part and a "left-hand" part that I need to record to? As far as I understand, the only thing that matters is the 16 MIDI channels. What did Yamaha mean by giving me a "left hand" part and a "right hand" part. I think the most intuitive way (for me, at least) is having a channel number and a voice, then I can just "go at it". Can anyone explain the logic?

Comment: Anything to do with the 'split point'?

Comment: @Tim most likely. But then again, it would make sense if they would say "1 voice per channel" and then it would be something else. But it looks like the right-hand / left-hand dichotomy is a key-concept.

Comment: The CVP-805 is a big Clavinova digital piano, right? If someone buys one, I suppose they want to play piano music. Piano music is almost always divided to left-hand and right-hand parts, and someone might want to practice these separately by recording one of the parts into a sequencer. Talking to piano students about MIDI channels doesn't make sense IMO.